# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable , error while iterating 2 lists

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am implementing bulk create but while iterating using destructuring i am getting this error,

**my view**

```
  job_skill_set = []
            for job_skll, job_lvl in zip(job_skill_, job_skill_level):
                skil_set = Skillset.objects.get(skill_name=job_skll)
                job_skill_set.append(Job_Skillset(
                    skill=skil_set, job_post=job_pst, skill_level=job_lvl))
                
            Job_Skillset.objects.bulk_create(job_skill_set)
    
            return redirect('/users/dashboard')
```

**error**

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

**trace**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\atif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\atif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\atif\PycharmProjects\my_proj\mysite_jobportal\job_management\views.py", line 50, in create_job
    for job_skll, job_lvl in zip(job_skill_, job_skill_level):

Exception Type: TypeError at /users/create_job/
Exception Value: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Share the *full* traceback.

Comment: Have you used variables with the name of zip by any change? Having the whole error message would also be useful.

Comment: yes I had , thanks issue resolved

Answer (score 1):

it had my mistake declared zip as an variable inside the file which led to an error !